# Pandas - How to search for a value when dataframe contains lists?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to search for a value in a dataframe of lists. For example if i search for **dog** it tells me its an **animal**. If i search for **holden** it tells me its a **car**.
My dataframe looks like this:

```
     type                                  group
0  animal                       [cat, dog, bird]
1     car  [chevy, ford, nissan, holden, bently]
```

My code is to find what type a dog is:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "type": ['animal', 'car'],
  "group": [['cat', 'dog', 'bird'], ['chevy', 'ford', 'nissan', 'holden', 'bently']]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

find = ['dog']

df = df[pd.DataFrame(df['group'].tolist()).isin(find).any(1).values]
print('You detected: ', df['type'])
```

I get this output:

```
You detected:  0    animal
Name: type, dtype: object
```

But I am trying to get this output with type only

You detected: animal

If I change `find = ['holden']` It returns:

```
You detected:  1    car
Name: type, dtype: object
```

I want this result `You detected: car`

**Is this the best and simpliest way to search for a single value in my dataframe?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `.item()` with column `loc` as well:

```
val = df.loc[pd.DataFrame(df['group'].tolist()).isin(find).any(1), 'type'].item()
print('You detected:', val)
```

Output:

```
You detected: animal
```